# Filtering key,values from a dict using values from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dict like so:

```
d = {27: 32, 28: 41, 29: 29, 30: 29, 31: 67, 32: 65}
```

And a list:

```
l = [27, 30, 31]

for n in l:
            d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in n}
```

Why is this not permissible? What can I do instead?

Comment: What do you mean *"not permissible"*? Why are you checking `k in n` - what would you expect from e.g. `27 in 27`? Did you mean `k in l`?

Comment: `n` is an integer, so `k` can't be "in" it. Do you want `d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in l}` (without the `for` loop) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be enough to get a filtered dict in this way:

```
d = {27: 32, 28: 41, 29: 29, 30: 29, 31: 67, 32: 65}
l = set([27, 30, 31])
d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in l}

print(d2)
```

The output:

```
{27: 32, 30: 29, 31: 67}
```

The expression `... if k in n` within your list comprehension while iterating through `for n in l:` means that you are searching a numerical key within a digit(number) - it's like we are searching `27 in 27` which is pointless in this case.
Also, `set` object would be preferable in case of large sequences.

> Membership testing with sets and dictionaries is much faster, O(1), than searching sequences, O(n)

Comment: Printing d2 just returns:
    {31: 0} for some reason

Comment: @user1893110 Use the exact code above ... your `for` loop is causing the problem.

Comment: Simple enough. For performance purposes, I'd use a set instead of a list, but this is tiny enough for it to not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do what you want is:

```
d2 = {k:d[k] for k in l}
```

If it's possible that `l` contains items that aren't keys in `d`:

```
d2 = {k:d[k] for k in l if k in d}
```

Comment: Would result in a `KeyError` being raised if anythin in `l` is not also in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a typo in your code:

```
d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in n}
```

`if k in n` produces

> TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

because `in` can be applied only to an iterable object.
If you change it to

```
 d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k == n}
```

it will work properly and produce

> d2
>   {31: 67}

Comment: But I'd also expect it to produce the key:value pairs for 27 and 30

Comment: @user1893110 than you shouldn't reassign in each iteration, but add to dictionary instead